# callback tabulator in node red

Tags: javascript, json, node-red, tabulator

hi hello every one I try to have a callback    wen  I move the row from table  after  lot of solution it don't work
can any one have an idea how to set the callback
in this example the callback return callback:'rowMoved' and don't return the 'payload'
its really confused

this the code from tabulator don't work :
 `rowMoved:function(row){ console.log("Row: " + row.getData().name + " has been moved"); }`
this is the parameter:

```
{
    "tabulator": {
        "layout": "responsiveLayout",
        "movableColumns": false,
        "groupBy": "",
        "movableRows": true,
        "cellEdited": "function(cell){this.send({topic:this.config.topic,ui_control:{callback:'cellEdited','payload':cell.value}})}",
        "rowMoved": "function(cell){this.send({ui_control:{callback:'rowMoved','payload':row}})}",
        "columns": [
            {
                "rowHandle": true,
                "formatter": "handle",
                "headerSort": false,
                "frozen": true,
                "width": 30,
                "minWidth": 30
            },
            {
                "formatterParams": {
                    "target": "_blank"
                },
                "title": "nummvt",
                "field": "nummvt",
                "width": 100,
                "frozen": true
            },
            {
                "formatterParams": {
                    "target": "_blank"
                },
                "title": "cloture",
                "field": "cloture",
                "width": 100,
                "align": "center"
            },
            {
                "formatterParams": {
                    "target": "_blank"
                },
                "title": "codepf",
                "field": "codepf",
                "width": 100,
                "align": "center"
            },
            {
                "formatterParams": {
                    "target": "_blank"
                },
                "title": "libpf",
                "field": "libpf",
                "width": 100,
                "align": "center"
            },
            {
                "formatterParams": {
                    "target": "_blank"
                },
                "title": "nbrdose",
                "field": "nbrdose",
                "width": 100,
                "align": "center"
            },
            {
                "formatterParams": {
                    "target": "_blank"
                },
                "title": "qtedose",
                "field": "qtedose",
                "width": 100,
                "align": "center"
            },
            {
                "formatterParams": {
                    "target": "_blank"
                },
                "title": "doseprod",
                "field": "doseprod",
                "width": 100,
                "align": "center"
            },
            {
                "formatterParams": {
                    "target": "_blank"
                },
                "title": "qteof",
                "field": "qteof",
                "width": 100,
                "align": "center"
            }
        ]
    },
    "customHeight": 12
}
```

really I want to found how can I access to the table parameter and modify it from tabulator
how can i write the methods of tabulator in node red
and change the theme of the table by sending the theme .
please can any one help

Comment: Which version of tabulator are you using?

Comment: i use version 5.5 ,!!!!